# VLOOKUP alternatives

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps, gs-vlookup

I am trying to do a VLOOKUP but its just not going to cut the mustard. There is no way I can alphabetize the first column in my list.

What I am wondering is there any alternatives or combinations of functions that I could use along VLOOKUP in the case that the list can not be alphabetized?

Comment: Why does the list have to be alphabetized? I don't use Google Docs but in Excel the VLOOKUP() function is searching for a value within a range of values and returns the first found instance.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah I am very familiar with how this is done in excel...sorting can be an issue with it as well: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx "The values in the first column of table_array must be placed in ascending sort order; otherwise, VLOOKUP may not give the correct value....."

Comment: real simple: I am trying to pull information from one worksheet to another. For example I have a list of products in column A of Sheet 1 and in Column B I have a list of prices. In another worksheet I have the same thing except its data from last year. Im comparing prices from this past year to the year before.

Comment: Order only matters if there are multiple instance of the value you are searching for. For example if you are looking for the value 'THE' and it is in your range 4 times the function returns the first instance found which may be the right value or not depending on what data you have. On the other had if 'THE' only appears once there is no need to sort the values because it can only be found the one time.

Comment: Please give an example, so we understand the alphabetize issue. (I have tried to answer below, but not 100% clear on the problem you face.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) in your comment on your OP:

> Range_lookup    A logical value that specifies whether you want
>   VLOOKUP to find an exact match or an approximate match:
>
> If TRUE or omitted, an exact or approximate match is returned. If an
>   exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than
>   lookup_value is returned.
>
> The values in the first column of
>   table_array must be placed in ascending sort order; otherwise, VLOOKUP
>   may not give the correct value. You can put the values in ascending
>   order by choosing the Sort command from the Data menu and selecting
>   Ascending. For more information, see Default sort orders.
>
> If FALSE, VLOOKUP will only find an exact match. In this case, the
>   values in the first column of table_array do not need to be sorted. If
>   there are two or more values in the first column of table_array that
>   match the lookup_value, the first value found is used. If an exact
>   match is not found, the error value #N/A is returned.

It isn't terribly obvious the way that document is formatted, but the qualification that the lookup range must be sorted ascending only applies for when the 4th argument in VLOOKUP is TRUE, or a non-zero positive number, or omitted. (If the 4th argument is a non-zero *negative* number, the first column must be sorted *descending*.) In these cases, you are allowing the formula to return a non-exact match.

**If you are looking for an exact match only, then you must specify FALSE (or zero) for the 4th argument, and the first column needn't be sorted at all.**

If you are looking for an non-exact match on an unsorted range, then something like this should work in Google Sheets (assuming you are looking for a match of C1 in column A, and returning the corresponding entry in column B):

`=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A:B;LEN(A:A));1;1);MATCH(C1;SORT(FILTER(A:A;LEN(A:A));1;1));2)`

Answer (score 0):

DGET - there are a bunch of database style functions in google spreadsheets, I suspect DGET is the one you want.

Comment: This is interesting. Thank you guys....I will dig in tonight and post back. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Plain Text**: With vlookup 1 and "1" are not the same. If you format the column as plain text it can do the lookup. This works even if your cell has a formula that produces a number.